# apply arguments to function

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions, named-parameters

I would like to apply arguments represented as a hash to a function.

For example, I would like to call this function:

```
myFunc = function(a,b,c) { return b }
```

In a way similiar to this:

```
myFunc({a:1, b:2, c:3})
```

Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Comment: why use 3 parameters instead of one object parameter, does it it make sense ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing right now. But i was hoping there is a better way.

Comment: currying normally works on tuples, not hashes.  In hashes, the elements are unordered.

Comment: you can use arguments variable inside function and iterate over it, of course it is not so clear as your propose, but it works :)

Comment: Have you tried something like this http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/namedfunction.shtml

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to associate positional arguments in a function with key-value pairs in an object in general.

It is possible to configure a function to take arguments both ways:

```
myFunc = function (objOrA, b, c) {
    var a = objOrA;
    if (objOrA.a || objOrA.b || objOrA.c) {
        a = objOrA.a;
        b || (b = objOrA.b);
        c || (c = objOrA.c);
    }
    return b;
};
```

If you have control over the function definition, however, the simplest solution is simply to require an object as the sole parameter no matter what.

```
myFunc = function (options) {
    return options.b;
}
```